# PDFLaTeX Font conflict (LuaLaTeX OK) XCharter + roboto-light get no Charter italics

Tags: fonts

As shown in the following MWE, with PDFLaTeX, combining XCharter.sty with roboto.sty and selecting the "light" option in Roboto somehow suppresses the Charter italics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[light]{roboto}
\begin{document}
Hello world.  \textit{This should be in italics!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output has  the second sentence in Charter upright.  Removing the "light" option in roboto.sty fixes the problem (as does compiling with LuaLaTeX)

Would prefer PDFLaTeX for speed (large document).

Thanks - Nathaniel

Comment: Sorry, should have added, this is with texlive 2022, didn't check other versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

latex does warn you

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/XCharter-TLF/l/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/XCharter-TLF/m/n' instead on input line 112.
```

so there is no light Xcharter normal shape, so it is using medium.

Then

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/XCharter-TLF/l/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/XCharter-TLF/l/n' instead on input line 6.
```

No light italic.

Both packages are designed to set all the document fonts but I guess you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[light]{roboto}
%\showoutput
\begin{document}
\fontseries{m}\selectfont
Hello world.  \textit{This should be in italics!}

{\fontseries{l}\sffamily Abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much David, that makes sense (though I guess LauLaTeX/fontspec have a different interpretation of things).  I use the sf family in well-defined places, so I can sprinkle \fontseries{l}'s in those places.